# Calc и переменные в SASS

Tags: css, веб-программирование, gulp, sass

Написал переменную. Начинаю представлять ее в calc. Gulp выдает ошибку. Как только убераю переменню из calc и ставлю обычное число все работает.[image: проблема calc и переменной]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Что б использовать переменную в значении обычного CSS нужно заключить переменную в #{}, Например:

```
top: calc(#{$border_padding} - 3px);
```

[Вот ссылка на документацию](https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/)

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Все заработало.